# AppEngine firewall for the particular service

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, firewall

I have to configure a firewall for the particular service from my AppEngine apps. Do you know how can I do it? As far as I see App engine firewall works for all services 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to do, and it has been previously raised in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110763628).

As mentioned there, your best choice would be to get that service 'out' of your proyect, as in deploy it in a different project, and there, use the firewall rules that you want to use.

Comment: I've found a workaround like:
- Create firewall rules you need
- Apply it to all instances with needed tag
- Deploy your app with same "instance_tag" value in app.yaml
It really applies firewall rules to app engine instances but doesn't work